# Clearing Vue JS v-for Select Field

Tags: vue.js, select, v-for

I have a simple application that uses a `v-for` in a `select` statement that generates two select tags. The `groupedSKUAttributes` variable that creates the `select` statement looks like this:

```
groupedSKUAttributes = {colour: [{id: 1, name: 'colour', value: 'red'},
                                 {id: 2, name: 'colour', value: 'blue'}],
                        size: [{id: 3, name: 'size', value: '40'},
                               {id: 4, name: 'size', value: '42'}]}
```

I also have a button that I want to clear the `select` fields. **How do I get the `clear` method to make each of the `select` fields choose their default `<option value='null' selected>select a {{ attributeName }}</option>` value?** I can't figure out if I'm meant to use a `v-model` here for the `groupedSKUAttributes`. Any advice would be appreciated.

The template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select
      v-for='(attribute, attributeName) in groupedSKUAttributes'
      :key='attribute'
      @change='update(attributeName, $event.target.value)'>
      <option value='null' selected>select a {{ attributeName }}</option>
      <option
        v-for='a in attribute'
        :value='a.id'
        :label='a.value'
        :key='a.id'>
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button @click='clear'>clear</button>
</template>
```

And the JS script looks like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      groupedSKUAttributes: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clear() {
      console.log('clear');
    },
    update(attributeName, attributeValue) {
      console.log(attributeName, attributeValue);
    },
    getSKUAttributes() {
      API
        .get('/sku_attribute/get')
        .then((res) => {
          this.skuAttributes = res.data;
          this.groupedSKUAttributes = this.groupBy(this.skuAttributes, 'name');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getSKUAttributes();
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-model` directive works within the v-for without any issues.

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',

    data() {
      return {
        groupedSKUAttributes: null,
        selected: {}
      }
    },

    methods: {
      clear() {
        this.generateDefaultSelected(this.generateDefaultSelected);
      },
      update(attributeName, attributeValue) {
        this.selected[attributeName] = attributeValue;
      },
      getSKUAttributes() {
        API
          .get('/sku_attribute/get')
          .then((res) => {
            this.skuAttributes = res.data;
            this.groupedSKUAttributes = this.groupBy(this.skuAttributes, 'name');

            // Call this method to reset v-model
            this.generateDefaultSelected(this.groupedSKUAttributes);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      },

      generateDefaultSelected(groupedSKUAttributes) {
        // Reset the object that maintains the v-model reference;
        this.selected = {};

        Object.keys(groupedSKUAttributes).forEach((name) => {
          // Or, set it to the default value, you need to select
          this.selected[name] = '';
        });
      }
    },

    created() {
      this.getSKUAttributes();
    }
  }
</script>
```

In the above code, `generateDefaultSelected` method resets the `selected` object that maintains the v-model for all your selects.

In the template, you can use `v-model` or unidirectional `value/@change` pair:

```
<!-- Using v-model -->
<select
  v-for='(attribute, attributeName) in groupedSKUAttributes'
  :key='attributeName' v-model="selected[attributeName]">


<!-- Unidirection flow without v-model -->
<select
  v-for='(attribute, attributeName) in groupedSKUAttributes'
  :key='attributeName' :value="selected[attributeName]"
  @change='update(attributeName, $event.target.value)'>
```